# failed to match connection hostname (api.shinyapps.io) against server certificate names

Tags: shiny, rstudio, shinyapps

when deploying a shiny app, rstudio ide shows the error:

Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  schannel: CertGetNameString() failed to match connection hostname (api.shinyapps.io) against server certificate names
Calls:  ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> 
Timing stopped at: 0.02 0.02 0.8
Execution halted

this is for windows 7(64bit).

the details:

```
----- Deployment log started at  2019-08-03 01:42:06  -----
Deploy command: 
 rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "D:/shinyTest/_app002",      appFileManifest = "C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/2013-805c-ca6a-04c2",      account = "r00", server = "shinyapps.io", appName = "_app002",      appTitle = "_app002", launch.browser = function(url) {         message("Deployment completed: ", url)     }, lint = FALSE, metadata = list(asMultiple = FALSE, asStatic = FALSE),      logLevel = "verbose") 

Session information: 
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                                                   
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1   rsconnect_0.8.15
Cookies: 
[1] "None"
----- Deployment error -----
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  schannel: CertGetNameString() failed to match connection hostname (api.shinyapps.io) against server certificate names
Calls: <Anonymous> ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>

----- Error stack trace -----
20: stop(e)
19: value[[3L]](cond)
18: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
17: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
16: tryCatch({
        response <- curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle)
    }, error = function(e, ...) {
        if (identical(e$message, "Callback aborted") || identical(e$message, 
            "transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining")) 
            return(NULL)
        else stop(e)
    })
15: system.time(gcFirst = FALSE, tryCatch({
        response <- curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle)
    }, error = function(e, ...) {
        if (identical(e$message, "Callback aborted") || identical(e$message, 
            "transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining")) 
            return(NULL)
        else stop(e)
    }))
14: http(service$protocol, service$host, service$port, method, url, 
        headers, timeout = timeout, certificate = certificate)
13: httpInvokeRequest(..., http = httpFunction())
12: httpRequest(service, authInfo, "GET", path, query, headers, timeout)
11: GET(service, authInfo, path, queryWithList)
10: grepl(contentType, response$contentType, fixed = TRUE)
9: isContentType(response, "application/json")
8: handleResponse(GET(service, authInfo, path, queryWithList))
7: listRequest(service, authInfo, path, query, "applications")
6: client$listApplications(accountInfo$accountId, filters = list(name = name))
5: getAppByName(client, accountInfo, target$appName)
4: applicationForTarget(client, accountDetails, target, forceUpdate)
3: force(code)
2: withStatus(paste0("Preparing to deploy ", assetTypeName), {
       application <- applicationForTarget(client, accountDetails, 
           target, forceUpdate)
   })
1: rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "D:/shinyTest/_app002", 
       appFileManifest = "C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/2013-805c-ca6a-04c2", 
       account = "r00", server = "shinyapps.io", appName = "_app002", 
       appTitle = "_app002", launch.browser = function(url) {
           message("Deployment completed: ", url)
       }, lint = FALSE, metadata = list(asMultiple = FALSE, asStatic = FALSE), 
       logLevel = "verbose")
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  schannel: CertGetNameString() failed to match connection hostname (api.shinyapps.io) against server certificate names
Calls: <Anonymous> ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Timing stopped at: 0.02 0.02 0.8
Execution halted
```

can anyone help me? thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue just yesterday and saw the same error when trying to deploy an app.  If you're like me, you searched and found that similar errors are observed [if you have a proxy server in the way](https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-deploying-shiny-app-due-to-error/36912).  With that being said, I am assuming that you are not behind a proxy server.  If you are, follow some of what is said elsewhere.

I am also assuming that you have previously setup your account via `rsconnect::setAccountInfo()`.  If not, follow the instructions on the [rsconnect documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rsconnect/rsconnect.pdf).

If all that is set, note the text of the error specifies that the issue is actually an error in the `curl` package:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :    schannel: CertGetNameString() failed to match connection hostname
>   (api.shinyapps.io) against server certificate names

The simple answer would be to update specifically the `curl` package: `install.packages('curl')`.  That worked for me... does that help?